# Getting Data from Database for HighCHarts

Tags: php, highcharts

I am developing a tool which has a statistic page on which I am using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo), I am using the basic line chart, Now to populate this chart I need some data. The data comes from my DB.

I got a query which extracts a list of users assigned to a particular 'Manager', Now I want each name to appear a s different line.

But What happens is that all names appear under one line........

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();
class ManagerStats{

    public function con()
    {
        require_once('connect.php');
        $DB = new dbConnect();
        return $DB->connect();
    }

    public function DontEvenKnow(){

        if($_SESSION['user'] == 'manager1@gmail.com'){

            $sql = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM tbl_user WHERE user_team='bob'";
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $sql);

            if($query){

                foreach($query as $v){

                    echo $v;

                }
            }

            }elseif($_SESSION['user'] == 'manager2@gmail.com'){
            //$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE user_team='oli'";
        }
        }
}
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#home_manager').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: '',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['04/19', '04/20', '04/21', '04/22', '04/23', '04/24']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Emails Sent'
                },
                plotLines: [
                    {
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }
                ]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: '<?php $oko = new ManagerStats(); $oko->DontEvenKnow(); ?>',
                    data: [38, 78, 12, 80, 75]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Helena',
                    data: [23, 34, 55, 67, 34]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Martin',
                    data: [34, 35, 55, 69, 67]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Marta',
                    data: [43, 64, 75, 57, 64]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Samuel',
                    data: [63, 64, 75, 87, 44]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Carter',
                    data: [43, 54, 55, 67, 84]
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function :

```
 $data = "";
 $data_for_user = "[43, 54, 55, 67, 84]"; 
           //For each user you need to get data from database,
           //but don't do a query inside a loop because it kills perfomance

 foreach($query as $v){
      $data .= " {
                   name: '".$v["first_name" ]."',
                   data: ".$data_for_user."
                }, ";
 }
  echo $data;
```

then in series

```
series: [<?php $oko = new ManagerStats(); $oko->DontEvenKnow(); ?>]
```

This will do a new line on highcharts foreach user that you have

UPDATE: was missing one of the quotes on the array that might be why it wasn't working for the person if they just copied it.

UPDATE: 
Getting data for more users for highcharts

You need a query with users and all his values that have to be in the graph:

```
 $query = "SELECT t.user_id, t.first_name, group_concat( v.values )  as data_for_user
             FROM tbl_user t,tbl_values v
            WHERE t.user_id = v.user_id 
            GROUP by t.user_id";
```

Group concat get the values for user separated by comma the way you need for highcharts.
Remember that group_concat have a lenght limit of 1024 but you can change it with this before your query.

```
 'SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000'
```

And data for highcharts

```
 $data = "";

 foreach($query as $v){
      $data .= " {
                   name: '".$v["first_name" ]."',
                   data: [".$v["data_for_user"]."]
                }, ";
 }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer looks decent, but it does not work, I get no results at all just a blank graph

Comment: Look at the edit that CipherLock made, maybe It works.

Comment: of course I have noticed the missing quote, but didn't wonna be picky :P, well I have tried all the provided solutions but still failing to achieve my goal, do you perhaps have some good read...?. thank you

Comment: What print  $oko = new ManagerStats(); $oko->DontEvenKnow();  ?? Print it and try in jsfidlle .  $oko->DontEvenKnow();  Had to print code like this {
                    name: 'Marta',
                    data: [43, 64, 75, 57, 64]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Samuel',
                    data: [63, 64, 75, 87, 44]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Carter',
                    data: [43, 54, 55, 67, 84]
                }

Comment: Ok I fixed few things around, everything works just the line is not generated

Comment: ok fixed it :) it was my mistake when i was posting the code i change the email address to one that does not exist in my database, and there was no results to show,

Comment: Now I just need a array of data graph numbers, so i can map more users onto the graph

Comment: Thx you once Again I love the group_concat() amazing, U deserve up vote but i cannot due to my points

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line break after you echo out the variable. Something like this:

```
echo $v . "<br />";
```

That should create a new line after each user.

Comment: HI thanks for your answer, but the result reminds the same, but now with your suggestion all happens is that the 2nd name goes one line down, but does not create new line

Comment: okay the break tag creates a new line. I think we need to define what you mean by a new line exactly. Is there some sort of visual representation of what you are wanting to do?